# Losing button functionality after changing the z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to create a horizontal scrolling website, single page, the content is placed in a panel with a 2000px.

Before - http://i44.tinypic.com/2psknsw.jpg 
After -  http://i41.tinypic.com/nltob7.png

the content and the youtube embed is placed under

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="events" class="panel">
        <p>..........</p>

        <div class="videoWrapper">
            <iframe></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
<body>
<html>
```

I've tried changing the z-index of the panel/videoWrapper, but i'm loosing the ability to click the play button. and the video is going behind the rectangle element. I've added the before and after results of changing the z-index.

Comment: Do you mean to say, that you are not able to click the video when video is behind the menu?

Comment: yes, i have image slider in the next panel, and when i try to change the z-index of that slider, it goes behind the menu and i lose the navigation buttons functionality of that slider.

Comment: I made a fiddle to try and understand what the problem is: http://jsfiddle.net/y89kE/ Video is clickable. Is your page header maybe the problem? Have you tried adding a padding top to the body that is equal to the height of your header?

Comment: yeah, it was the header. I have put the #banner in a new class and put the z-index: 999 which solved the problem. Thanks for the help @toast :)